# Unable to draw vertices with Z axis on screen

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I need to plot few coordinates on screen, the coordinates without Z axis get displayed but the coordinates with Z axis values aren't being displayed. I tried normalizing the coordinates before plotting them which worked. When normalized all the coordinates get plotted. But in the case of unnormalized coordinates the vertices with Z axis are hidden.

OpenGL Version : ES 2.0

Coordinates:

```
float squareCoords[] = {
            202.00002f, 244.00002f, 0.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 0.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 0.0f,
            690.00006f, 186.0f,0.0f,

            202.00002f, 244.00002f, 50.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 50.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 50.0f,
            690.00006f, 186.0f, 50.0f
    };
```

indices:

```
short[] drawOrder = {
            0,1,2,3,
            0,4,
            1,5,
            2,6,
            4,5,6,7
    };
```

Draw Code:

```
 GLES20.glDrawElements(
                GLES20.GL_LINES, drawOrder.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
```

On Surface Changed code:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

        float ratio = (float) mWidth / mHeight;

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, 0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0, 50);

    }
```

OnDraw:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        Square square = new Square();
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (mFirstDraw)
            mFirstDraw = false;

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
      float angle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
       // float angle = 90;
       // Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
       // angle += 0.7f;
        if (angle > 360f)
            angle = 0f;
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 4f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        // projection x view = modelView
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
        // Creating rotation matrix
        Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angle, -1f, 0f, 0f);

        // rotation x camera = modelView
        float[] duplicateMatrix = Arrays.copyOf(mMVPMatrix, 16);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, duplicateMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0);

        square.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    }
```

I'm rotating the diagram to figure out whether the vertices on Z axis are drawn.

I personally think this line is the culprit, here I've given far value 50 and near value 0. I wonder what these values should be

```
Matrix.orthoM(mProjMatrix, 0, 0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0, 50);
```

Comment: Have you tried -50?  OpenGL usually assumes -z to be the depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the value of far wasn't higher enough. I put far as 500

```
Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, 0f, width, 0.0f, height,0, 500);
```

and changed the coordinates to:

```
float squareCoords[] = {
            202.00002f, 244.00002f, 0.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 0.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 0.0f,
            690.00006f, 186.0f,0.0f,

            202.00002f, 244.00002f, 200.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 200.0f,
            440.00003f, 625.00006f, 200.0f,
            690.00006f, 186.0f, 200.0f
    };
```

Its working now.